# Positioning/centering a diagram with picture environment

Tags: positioning

i just put up some Dynkin diagram (already thanks to you guys :)) but it appears that this is too large fir the page and is thus not centered, as the code shows :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
$A_n$&
\begin{picture}(7,2)(0,0)

\put(0,1){\tikzmark{z}\circle*{3}}
\put(0,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(20,1){\circle*{3}}

\put(25,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(42,1){\tikzmark{t}\circle*{3}}
\put(42,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(62,1){\tikzmark{zg}\circle*{3}}
\put(62,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(82,1){\tikzmark{za}\circle*{3}}

\put(87,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(104,1){\tikzmark{zb}\circle*{3}}
\put(104,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(124,1){\tikzmark{zh}\circle*{3}}
\put(124,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(144,1){\circle*{3}}

\put(149,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}
\put(165,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(183,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(183,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(203,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(203,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(223,1){\tikzmark{zc}\circle*{3}}

\put(228,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(245,1){\tikzmark{zd}\circle*{3}}
\put(245,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(265,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(265,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(285,1){\tikzmark{ze}\circle*{3}}

\put(290,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(307,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(307,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(327,1){\tikzmark{zf}\circle*{3}}

\put(62,1){\circle{7}}
\put(124,1){\circle{7}}
\put(203,1){\circle{7}}
\put(265,1){\circle{7}}



  \end{picture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:z})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:t}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $y-1$};


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:za})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zb}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $z-1$};


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:zc})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zd}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $t-1$};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:ze})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zf}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $x-1$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

i would like to know if it would be possible to center it, making it go a bit left and be centered even if its slightly larger than it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enclosed the `tabular` in a `{\centering\noindent\makebox[20pt]{...}}`.  It centers the
makebox.  Normally, the makebox would be 0pt in width (allowing symmetric bleed into the left and right margins), but because of your overlay, the image was slightly off center.  Allowing the tabular to be centered over a 20pt box took care of the offset.

And, as egreg pointed out, a vertical gap needs to be introduced after the image, to avoid overlap with subsequent text.  A `\vspace{1cm}`, for example, would suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 

\vspace{1cm}

{\centering\noindent\makebox[20pt]{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$A_n$&
\begin{picture}(7,2)(0,0)

\put(0,1){\tikzmark{z}\circle*{3}}
\put(0,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(20,1){\circle*{3}}

\put(25,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(42,1){\tikzmark{t}\circle*{3}}
\put(42,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(62,1){\tikzmark{zg}\circle*{3}}
\put(62,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(82,1){\tikzmark{za}\circle*{3}}

\put(87,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(104,1){\tikzmark{zb}\circle*{3}}
\put(104,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(124,1){\tikzmark{zh}\circle*{3}}
\put(124,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(144,1){\circle*{3}}

\put(149,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}
\put(165,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(183,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(183,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(203,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(203,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(223,1){\tikzmark{zc}\circle*{3}}

\put(228,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(245,1){\tikzmark{zd}\circle*{3}}
\put(245,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(265,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(265,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(285,1){\tikzmark{ze}\circle*{3}}

\put(290,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(307,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(307,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(327,1){\tikzmark{zf}\circle*{3}}

\put(62,1){\circle{7}}
\put(124,1){\circle{7}}
\put(203,1){\circle{7}}
\put(265,1){\circle{7}}



  \end{picture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:z})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:t}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $y-1$};


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:za})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zb}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $z-1$};


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:zc})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zd}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $t-1$};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:ze})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zf}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $x-1$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should give a correct bounding box to begin with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test
\[
A_n\quad
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\unitlength}
\rule[-20\unitlength]{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{picture}(330,0)% <----------------- the bounding box

\put(0,1){\tikzmark{z}\circle*{3}}
\put(0,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(20,1){\circle*{3}}

\put(25,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(42,1){\tikzmark{t}\circle*{3}}
\put(42,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(62,1){\tikzmark{zg}\circle*{3}}
\put(62,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(82,1){\tikzmark{za}\circle*{3}}

\put(87,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(104,1){\tikzmark{zb}\circle*{3}}
\put(104,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(124,1){\tikzmark{zh}\circle*{3}}
\put(124,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(144,1){\circle*{3}}

\put(149,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}
\put(165,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(183,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(183,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(203,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(203,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(223,1){\tikzmark{zc}\circle*{3}}

\put(228,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(245,1){\tikzmark{zd}\circle*{3}}
\put(245,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(265,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(265,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(285,1){\tikzmark{ze}\circle*{3}}

\put(290,-1.5){\mbox{$\cdots$}}

\put(307,1){\circle*{3}}
\put(307,1){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(327,1){\tikzmark{zf}\circle*{3}}

\put(62,1){\circle{7}}
\put(124,1){\circle{7}}
\put(203,1){\circle{7}}
\put(265,1){\circle{7}}
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:z})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:t}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $y-1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:za})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zb}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $z-1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:zc})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zd}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $t-1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt]({pic cs:ze})+(-0.1pt,-3pt) coordinate (c) -- (c -| {pic cs:zf}) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.4cm] {\footnotesize $x-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test

\end{document}
```

No `tabular` is necessary. But a rule to take into account the depth is also necessary, or the text below the diagram will overlap it.

For squeezing the diagram a bit, I just reduced `\unitlength` to 90% of the default value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dynkin-diagrams` package. Your diagram doesn't turn out too large, but you could change the edge lengths if you needed to.

[image: Example of braces in Dynkin diagrams]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\newcommand\circleRoot[1]{\draw (root #1) circle (3pt);}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}{A}{**.***.***.***.***.**}
\circleRoot{4}\circleRoot{7}\circleRoot{10}\circleRoot{13}
\dynkinBrace[y-1]{1}{3}
\dynkinBrace[z-1]{5}{6}
\dynkinBrace[t-1]{11}{12}
\dynkinBrace[x-1]{14}{16}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```